# List of Dicts in Redis

Tags: python, redis

How to keep a list of dicts in Redis against a key using Python-redis. The following is the data structure which I am aiming at:

```
'browsing_history' : {
    'session_key_1' : [{'image': 'image-url', 'url' : 'url', 'title' : 'test_title', 'description' : 'test_description'}, {''image': 'image-url2', 'url' : 'url2', 'title' : 'test_title2', 'description' : 'test_description2'}],
    'session_key_2' : [{'image': 'image-url', 'url' : 'url', 'title' : 'test_title', 'description' : 'test_description'}, {''image': 'image-url2', 'url' : 'url2', 'title' : 'test_title2', 'description' : 'test_description2'}],
}
```

Would like to add into the session lists as well as add new sessions and also retrive them. How can I do this using Python-redis?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Serialize your dictionary `{'image': 'image-url', 'url' : 'url', 'title' : 'test_title', 'description' : 'test_description'}` with [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps) or [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.dumps). Use redis list to store them as strings. Use keys like `browsing_history:SESSION_KEY_1` to access those lists. If you need to get a list of all session keys you probably will need to maintain a set of strings for keys `browsing_history:*`.

Comment: This is interesting at face value but I'm concerned about reading and iterating. Iterating through this list requires deserializing every item. Appends are fast under this methodology.

Comment: When loading data from any source into python objects deserialization step is mandatory all the time. Most database drivers do this for you so often it's not visible.

Answer (score 4):

A solution not requiring serialization and not restricted by the limits on string sizes (but not necessarily more performant) is to store each dict in its own dedicated hash map:

```
# define root name for hashes used 
# to store list elements - dicts
hash_root_name='test_hash'

# sample list of dicts
dicts_list=[test_dict1, test_dict2]

# store dicts from the list to consecutively 
# named redis hashes,  with list indices 
# appended to hash root name
for i in range(len(dicts_list)):
    
    redis_client.hmset(hash_root_name+str(i), 
                       dicts_list[i])
```